# read/write operation to text file from asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, read-write

I am trying to read/write to text file located at the root of my website. I am using asp.net development server (my local machine).

When I read the file it's throwing this exception

```
Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\error.txt' is denied.
```

I am using following lines of code to read/write from text file

```
 var text = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("error.txt"));
    File.WriteAllText(@"error.txt", text + " \n " + "newnewnew text");
```

What is the problem, why my server.MapPath retrieving path of my c drive? When it should retrieve absolute path of my site, that is

```
website1/error.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change following line

```
File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("error.txt"));
```

to

```
File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/error.txt"));
```

It will search file in root directory of application. If you have file stored in folder called "MyFiles" inside root directory then path will be something like below

```
File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/MyFiles/error.txt"));
```

Hope this helps.